# Does 'get involved' have negative connotations?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

When you use the phrase 'get involved', do you expect an object for it should be negative?

I've seen some examples using it since now. Their objects were mostly negative.

Examples:

> get involved in a bribery affair
>    get involved in a quarrel
>   get involved in an accident

Comment: I've been involved with EL&U for awhile now, and I don't think that's a negative thing.

Comment: Thanks guys for helps. I got that. Also, Andrew, thank you for your editing. it's good to know better way to ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When you use the phrase 'get involved', do you expect an object for it
>   should be negative?

No, a negative object isn't *expected* (nor is a positive one). One can ***get involved*** in positive things too, such as one's community, church, hackerspace, &c.

Comment: It might be more common usage to get involved in good things. But it is *also* correct to say "They might get involved in a quarrel", or bribery, or an accident. All were given as examples in the question.

Comment: @FeralOink Do you feel that my answer says otherwise?  My 'no' refers to OP's direct question, "do you expect an object for it should be negative?"

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you mean now! I misread that. You were saying No, he should not expect negative things and you gave examples of positives. I see. You said the same as I, that get involved could refer to positive OR negative. I'm sorry. I can't remove my down vote now. I thought your answer was 100% wrong, because of how I misunderstood it, and that's why I downvoted.

Comment: @FeralOink I will edit my answer!

Comment: Thank you! Down vote reversed, replaced with up vote. I never did that as a single step. Kind of cool to see the vote count flip from 4 straight to 6!

Answer (score 2):

One may ***get involved*** in activities with negative **OR** positive connotations. The phrase *get involved* is entirely unrelated to the subject matter to which it is applied. A few examples of involvement in situations that are perceived as having less social merit, or deleterious to an individual's well-being:

> **[People get involved in the illegal drug trade because it is lucrative](http://www.un.org/News/Press/docs/1998/19980610.ga9421.html)**

or

> **[He might get involved in fraud](http://m.npr.org/news/Science/151764534?singlePage=true)**

Of course, one may get involved with a civic society, a charity or volunteer organization, church group, advocacy effort for the disenfranchised, or a new coding project, all of which are positive.